# Does the position of WHEN change anything?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Lately I’ve been talking to him **when** he *asked* me about my wife on
> purpose.

I am sure the sentence is wrong, because of "asked". It should be either ASKS or HAS ASKED. What if we change WHEN?

> Lately **when** I’ve been talking to him, he *asked* me about my wife on
> purpose.

Is sentence 2 correct or still wrong?

Comment: The mistake isn't ***asked*** - it's that you should have written *Lately I **was** talking to him*. The advice remains unchanged: *Avoid Perfect verb forms wherever possible*.

Comment: A valid construction (that probably *doesn't* mean what you're trying to say here) is *Lately when I’ve been talking to him, he **asks** me about my wife on purpose.* That means I've talked to him on several occasions lately, and when I do he usually / always asks about my wife. Though what you mean by ***on purpose*** here is beyond me. How can you *accidentally* ask someone about their wife?

Comment: On purpose means that there is no need asking about her every time but the person still does it.

Comment: No - "on purpose" means "deliberately" (opposite of "accidentally"), not "unnecessarily" (opposite of "unavoidably").

Comment: Is that a meaning of _on purpose_ where you come from, user1425? It does not have that meaning British English, or I think American English.

Comment: So, how do you understand "He did it on purpose"?

Comment: The word you're looking for is  probably ***pointedly***.

Comment: Sentence 2 makes a lot more sense.  Sentence 1 makes it sound like you are talking to him **because** he has asked about your wife, but the tenses don't really work.  (*on purpose* makes no sense in either sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that *when* really needs to be ***whenever***. The tenses also need to match.

How about: ***Lately I've been talking to him whenever he has asked me about my wife***.

I'm not clear what is meant by *on purpose*. Does it mean you have been talking to him "on purpose", or he has been asking about your wife "on purpose"?

Can you try and fit that into my suggested sentence?

Comment: After you put WHENEVER, I've started to understand the sentence differently from the original. Your sentence sounds as "He asks me about my wife first, then I start talking to him." May be I see it wrongly.

Comment: I'm conscious of the various suggestions made by @Fumble Fingers and Colin Fine and quite clearly the original sentence is quite confusing and could mean various different things. Where did it come from? Not from a native speaker, I suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with WS2 that "whenever" is needed.

> Lately, whenever I have talked to him he has asked about my wife.
>
> These days whenever I talk to him he asks about my wife.

If you want to say there is **no need** for him to ask about her every time,

> Lately whenever I have talked to him he has asked quite needlessly
> about my wife.
>
> These days whenever I talk to him he asks quite needlessly
> about my wife.

or use "***unnecessarily** about*."

If the man simply asks, "How is your wife?" we would say, *he **asks after** my wife*.

Comment: But WS2 put WHENEVER into a different position.  Lately I've been talking to him whenever he has asked me about my wife.

Comment: I agreed with him that "whenever" was needed. I didn't agree about where it should be put!